# Rails migrations think that I'm trying to change the table named either symbol or string depending on my syntax usage.... WHY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, macos

So, I have this migration line:

```
  add_column :users, :account_id, :integer
```

which gives the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: symbols: ALTER TABLE "symbols" ADD "account_id" integer
```

But when I do

```
  add_column "users", "account_id", "integer" #changed everything to strings
```

I get i similar error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: account_id: ALTER TABLE "strings" ADD "account_id" integer
```

NOTE:
• it doesn't matter whether or not I use add_column's parenthesis ( add_column(args) ).
• no where in any of my migrations to I ever mention any tables that could be named "strings" or "symbols"

So, it appears that whatever the object type of the table I'm trying to modify is, it mistakingly thinks that I want to modify a table named after that object type. =\

According to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html
my syntax is correct.

These migrations work on another machine, so it IS an environment issue.

I'm using Mac OS X lion.
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 2.3.8
Rake 0.8.7

EDIT (as requested): The Migration: http://pastebin.com/xhwP8TFy

Comment: Please post the entire contents of your migration file.

Comment: It's just the standard Rails Kit migration. I'll add a link.

Comment: That's one huge migration :) Is "Rails Kit" a special tool? I'm unfamiliar with the practice of putting both table create code and table column adds code in the same migration...

Comment: Yeah, it's a rails tool thing by the rails people: http://railskits.com/saas/

Comment: but still. IT happens on EVERY add_column. I've been manually adding tho columns, and manually changing the version number in the schema_migrations table. =\

Comment: could you create a minimal rails project with just a single migration (one add_columns). Does the error still occur, if yes, could you upload it somehwere (github?), if not, could you try to add the plugins you use to see wether something is triggering that bug?

Comment: well, I think it might be related to rails 2.3.8, cause my rails 3 project worked just fine. =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, because Stackoverflow has stupid rules, I have to use two different accounts.

Found out, that it was because of how I extended the "object" class.  In config/initializers, I had some object methods.

And there was a conflict apparently. Though it never told my anything about it.

So... Don't extend object in that folder, I guess.